# (Rails 5.1) Self-join association gives error: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### **FIXED**

**It works in 5.0.6**

The problem is within your generator.

```
rails g model Employees manager:references
```

Produces the wrong migration. Read on if you want the fix.

I have a problem with self-join associations...

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"

    belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee", optional: true
end
```

When trying to create a "Employee" record, gives error "No such table main.managers" (at the bottom):

```
>> Employee.create(name: "Matt")
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "employees" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Matt"], ["created_at", "2018-02-19 16:38:21.835022"], ["updated_at", "2018-02-19 16:38:21.835022"]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.managers: INSERT INTO "employees" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

The code is taken out from the RoR guide. How do I correct it?

I emphasize that it is a self-join table. Therefore there is no "Manager" model or "managers" table.

Rails version 5.1.5

### **Solution:**

It's because of the migration.
Using the command

```
rails g model Employee name:string manager:references
```

Produces different code in 5.0.6 . You cannot have such a migration:

```
create_table :employees do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.references :manager, foreign_key: true #mistake

  t.timestamps
end
```

Change it to:

```
t.references :manager, index: true
```

[RoR self-join guide I'm referring to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins)

Comment: Which rails version are you using? Tested your code with 5.0.6 and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me also in 5.0.6.

Comment: I just did an install of Rails 5.1.5 on Ruby 2.5.0 and your model code works fine for me against sqlite3 version 3.14.2 with gem version 1.3.13.  What does your migration look like?

Comment: Thanks! I had a problem with my migration.

Comment: you saved my time! thanks!

Comment: great self answer

Answer (score 0):

If employee belongs_to manager,then you should have something like this Manager.employee.create

Answer (score 0):

Set the `foreign_key` property on your `belongs_to` association as well.

Comment: I think you may have added something into one of your migrations that's throwing that error.  Can you show what your migrations look like? (Or your schema.rb file)?